# 2d overlay elements not rendering over Scene Kit scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, overlay, scenekit

I'm using an SKScene as an overlay over my Scene Kit scene, but when I add a child node to the SKScene it doesn't render to the screen.  Here is my code(truncated):

```
import SceneKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController {

var scene = SCNScene()
var overlay = SKScene()
var expand = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "expand")
var trash = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "trash")
var palette = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "palette")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // set up scene

        let sceneView = view as! SCNView
        sceneView.backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()
        sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
        sceneView.showsStatistics = false

        setupScene()

        sceneView.scene = scene

        sceneView.pointOfView = cameraNode
        sceneView.overlaySKScene = overlay

        setupEnvironment()
        setupHud()
    }

    func setupHud() {
        var sizeOfModifiers = (expand.frame.size.width + trash.frame.size.width + palette.frame.size.width) / 2
        trash.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
        palette.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
        expand.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
        trash.position = CGPointMake((view.frame.width / 2) - sizeOfModifiers, 0)
        palette.position = CGPointMake(trash.position.x + trash.frame.size.width, 0)
        expand.position = CGPointMake(palette.position.x + trash.frame.size.width, 0)
        overlay.addChild(trash)
        overlay.addChild(palette)
        overlay.addChild(expand)
    }
}
```

From what I see here, the code is written correctly.  The images are loading, but it doesn't get rendered over the 3d elements in the scene.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question prematurely.  From my research, the SKScene needs to be a separate class.  I made a schoolboy error.